# Same call returning different JSON results on Android vs iOS

Tags: php, android, ios, c, json

**Background:**

I'm writing something for the Pebble Smartwatch using the generic HTTPebble library to act as a bridge between the watch and the phone. This requires a specific iOS application and a different Android application, although both use the same framework and library.

**Problem:**

I am able to do a HTTP call to a PHP server, and successfully return and decode a JSON tuplet result from Android Gingerbread. However, when using the same call on iOS devices, I am unable to receive a valid expected result.

Here is the code I am using to receive the JSON result:

```
#define INTRO_DAY1_ICON 1
Tuple*   icon    = dict_find(received,INTRO_DAY1_ICON);
if (icon){
    dayTransition.day[0].currentWeather = icon->value->int8;
```

I am expecting icon->value->int8 to be an integer value of 0, 1, 2, 3, 11 or 99. On Android, this is currently working as intended. But, on iOS I always seem to return a result of 8.Going further, the icon returns a value of > 50,000 (has data) via Android whereas it returns a value of 0 on iOS.

Even more puzzling, is that the example code provided is able to return valid results on both devices, yet mirroring that functionality with my code does not produce the same results. (Meaning that the data_tuple is filled when called from either device)
That code is as follows:

```
    Tuple* data_tuple = dict_find(received, WEATHER_KEY_CURRENT);
    if(data_tuple) {
         uint16_t value = data_tuple->value->int16;
         uint8_t icon = value >> 11;
         if(icon < 10) {
```

Any ideas as to why this could be occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! I believe that the issue was how the data is interpreted on iOS vs Android. On Android, I could just pass back any sort of integer (signed or unsigned, 8, 16, or 32 bit) and it would just seem to work out. However, on iOS, I needed to do a bitwise shifting process on the JSON Output (before encoding) to make it into an unsigned 16 bit integer. Then once it got back to the Pebble, there is code to shift that unsigned 16 bit integer into an unsigned 8 bit integer, before assigning it to a standard c int

```
uint16_t value1 = icon_tuple1->value->int16;
uint8_t icon1 = value1 >> 11;
dayTransition.day[0].currentWeather = icon1;
```

TL;DR
Shift your JSON >> 11, return to device, then unshift it << 11 in the received phase on the device.